# Unable to redirect url for facebook http user agent

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, apache, .htaccess

I created simple application using Angular JS template engine but when I share the url in social media contents are not parsed it shows '{{}}' so I worked around using htaccess. whenever facebook requests my http://website.com/posts/value-1 I want it to redirect to static php file at http://website.com/static.php?id=$1 but it is not redirecting using the below htaccess file , Any Solutions ?

```
RewriteEngine on
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /pages/index.html
  Redirect /index.html http://website.com/home/

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9](+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)|Twitterbot|Pinterest|facebot/[0-9]|Google.*snippet)
  RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/static.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `escaped fragment` method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003186/facebook-scrapper-and-angular-app-with-html5mode-hashbang-urls.

Comment: @Roemer Thank you it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it myself below is the working .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /pages/index.html
  Redirect /index.html http://website.com/home/

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9](+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)|Twitterbot|Pinterest|facebot/[0-9]|Google.*snippet)
  RewriteRule ^(posts)/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/static.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```